# Maximum valid time from 4 digits

Tags: java

I am trying to find the maximum valid time from given 4 digits. I have used digits (2,4,0,0). The code returnS 20:42 while it should return 20:40.
Any Suggestions on how to approach this ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MaxTimeCombination {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(solution(2, 4, 0, 0));
    System.out.println(solution(3, 0, 7, 0));
}

public static String solution(int A, int B, int C, int D) {
    // brute force permutation
    int[] temp = new int[] {A, B, C, D};

    List<List<Integer>> permutation = permute(temp);
    int h = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int m = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    boolean exists = false;

    /*      System.out.println("Permutations:" + permutation);
    for (int i = 0; i < permutation.size(); i++) {
    if (permutation.get(i).get(0) > 0  && permutation.get(i).get(0) < 3 ){
        List <Integer> output = permutation.get(i);
        System.out.println(output);     
    }

    }*/


    for (int i = 0; i < permutation.size(); i++) {
        //if (permutation.get(i).get(0) > 0  && permutation.get(i).get(0) < 3 ){
        List<Integer> k = permutation.get(i);
        //System.out.println("Sorted :" + k);
        int hh = k.get(0)*10 + k.get(1);
        if (hh < 24) {
            exists = true;
            if (hh > h) {
                h = hh;
            } 
        } 
        int mm = k.get(2)*10 + k.get(3);

        if ( mm < 60) {
            exists = true;
            if (mm > m) {
                m = mm;
            } 
        } 
    }

    return (exists ? String.format("%02d:%02d", h, m) : "NOT POSSIBLE");
}

public static List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] num) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    //start from an empty list
    result.add(new ArrayList<>());

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        //list of list in current iteration of the array num
        List<List<Integer>> current = new ArrayList<>();

        for (List<Integer> l : result) {
            // # of locations to insert is largest index + 1
            for (int j = 0; j < l.size()+1; j++) {
                // + add num[i] to different locations
                l.add(j, num[i]);

                List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(l);
                current.add(temp);

                //System.out.print(temp + " ");

                //l.remove(num[i]); 
                l.remove(j);
            }

        }

        result = new ArrayList<>(current);
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: it seems it is returning correct answer could you please elaborate how maximum valid is 20:40 rather then 20:42 :/

Comment: I guess because the fourth entered Number would not be used then @ZainUlAbidin . If you don't want the 2, to appear again you could blacklist it after using it once.

Comment: Because you know the output format, just have 4 digits. So why don't you combine input into integer with 4 digits => Filter max integer that have 2 first digit <= 23 with the rest part <= 59 => Format into time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your tests for h and m max. Your current code looks for the max of each independently. What you're getting is the max hour along with the max minute, even when they did not occur together in a permutation, as with 20:42.

Here's a working version of the tests.

```
int hh = k.get(0) * 10 + k.get(1);          
if (hh < 24)
{
    if (hh >= h)
    {
        int mm = k.get(2) * 10 + k.get(3);
        if (mm < 60)
        {
            exists = true;
            if (hh > h || mm > m)
            {
                m = mm;
            }
            h = hh;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `hh>h` has become `hh>=h`. Even if the hour is equal to one we've seen before we need to look for a maximal minute. The code that checks for max minute has been moved within the if clause of the hour test. We need to be sure that the minute we're considering is associated with a maximal hour. Finally, we need to update the max minute when `mm>m` or we have a new max hour, `hh>h`

With this change your code gives the expected value: `20:40`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking for this problem. Please find the working solution as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class TestClass{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int maxLimits[] = {2, 3, 5, 9};

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();    
        list.add(3);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(2);

        Collections.sort(list);
        int time[] = new int[4];

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            int index = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++)
            {

                if (list.get(j) <= maxLimits[i]) 
                {
                    time[i] = list.get(j);
                    index = j;
                }
            }

            list.remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will be helpful. :-)